# Risks giving wooden toys to parrots

Tags: safety, toys, parrots, cockatiels

I am starting to give my cockatiels wood so they use it as a toy, destroying it. I know there are many toys made out of wood, but isn't it possible for them to get hurt with the splinters if they eat them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 2 African greys, about 25 and 20 years. We have found "a busy beak is a happy beak". They love to tear things apart, never had a problem with splinters. Their favorite is chicken leg bones, they turn them into sawdust getting the marrow. Chicken bones are probably too big for cockatiels.

Comment: "...too big for cockatiels.." . you'd be surprised!  We had Rosellas (roughly same size as cockatiels - maybe slightly larger), and they'd handle a chicken drumstick like a pro!!  LOL (gawd they love that marrow!!)