# Can I use bamboo for Indian ringneck parrot toys?

Tags: birds, toys, parrots

Similar to [Risks giving wooden toys to parrots](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28038/risks-giving-wooden-toys-to-parrots)

I have lots of bamboo in my yard, can I use it for 'chew toys' in my Indian ringnecks' cage?
Is it safe for them to chew on / eat?

I can't afford to buy new toys from the pet store every week!

Answer (score 1):

I would not fear for the parrot in a fight with a piece of wood, generally speaking. However, not all wood is the same. Bamboo tends to be on the tougher side of the fibers, and over time it might become a problem - the parrot's beak might get hurt.

A middle ground would be to go to any business dealing with natural untreated wood and get from there pieces of soft wood - preferably without resin (i.e., no Christmas trees).

---

Alternative: additionally to wood, you might want to supply your parrots with cuttlebone. Not only it gives them destructive activity, but it delivers them some good amount of healthy calcium.

---

When we had budges, we gradually stopped having plants in the house. Not only they destroyed all live plants, but went systematically even through plastic plants.

Comment: hahaha yeah they love to destroy. the bamboo grows really quick. also the outer layer is toughest which i can shave off with a knife. it has a bit of resin but i think putting a flame over it cleans that up. these are just observations on the properties of bamboo and i have no scientific knowledge of it at all. any thoughts on those points? i think i'll get more cuttlebone and other wood, they're great ideas thanks! i'll just introduce some bamboo as an extra distraction to keep him busy

Comment: I know that bamboo is used for flooring because it is tough. It is also not really recommended for cutting boards in the kitchen because it dulls knives faster than other types of wood. I have no personal experience with live bamboo - except for the lucky bamboo, which is in fact just dracaena.